# Drop Table in SQL Database from Azure Databricks

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, pyspark

I need to drop a table in SQL Database using Azure Databricks (PySpark).

I am required to not use anything outside PySpark to achieve this. Can this be done to using DataFrameWriter. Below code (internally I believe) first deletes the table and then creates a new table with the same name and then writes the dataframe data into the table.

```
MyDataFrame.write.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://<SQLServerHost>.windows.net:1433").option("database", 'MyDBName').option("dbtable", 'MyTableName').option("user", "MyUsername").option("password", "MyPassword").mode('overwrite').save()
```

I want to simply delete the table completely. Is there a code to do the same?

regards,
Sree

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following.

```
#Setup the JDBC connection. 
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://{0}:{1}/{2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)
connectionProperties = {
      "user" : jdbcUsername,
      "password" : jdbcPassword,
      "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    }

#Create a query to drop the required table
pushdown_query = "DROP table tablename"

#run the query
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
display(df)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Vikas, Thanks for your response. I receive an error stating java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. Not sure where to check the same on Azure databricks cluster. Any ideas ???

Comment: Yes I did. It gives me the said error - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. Found that I want to connect to SQLServer and hence changed the driver. Now I receive a separate error - com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword &apos;DROP&apos;.

Comment: Hi All, Any ideas here??

Comment: yeah, seems like you didn't had the driver first, but once you had the driver, the command i have wasn't right. I have edited it.

Comment: Could you, if you get time, check the code by running it? I am trying to understand why the answer was downvoted, even when it helped partially

Comment: Hi Vikas, I ran the code you mentioned. It still gives an error. Somehow the table=pushdownQuery doesn't work. I did try it. Gives the same Incorrect syntax near drop error. i had already tried the Drop Table TableName but had given me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = spark.read.format('jdbc')\
.option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://MyServerName:MyPort")\
.option("database", 'MyDBName')\
.option("user", "MyUser")\
.option("password", "MyPassword")\
.option('query', 'drop table tablename')
```

this did the trick.