# How to drop table or drop row on Databricks with Azure Synapse?

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I want to drop my table using `DROP TABLE`, but I got an error JDBC on my Databricks, but if I use `SELECT`, it doesn't get any error, I have 2 function different that can `read_from_synapse` and `write_to_synapse`.

This is my `read_from_synapse`, that I think can `DROP TABLE` use query

```
def read_from_synapse(sql, url, tempDir):
       df = (spark.read
              .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")
              .option("url", url)
              .option("tempDir", tempDir)
              .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true")
              .option("query", sql)
              .load()
       )
       
       return df
```

And this is my `write_to_synapse` script that can insert into a table

```
def write_to_synapse(df, table, write_mode, url, tempDir):
       df.write
              .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")
              .option("tableOptions", "CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX, DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN") # Added at 20200121
              .option("url", url)
              .option("dbtable", table)
              .option("forward_spark_azure_storage_credentials","True")
              .option("tempdir", tempDir)         
              .mode(write_mode)
              .save()
```

**Updated**

I have tried this link, and it didn't solve my problem, it got an error like this

```
com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDWSideException: Azure Synapse Analytics failed to execute the JDBC query produced by the connector.
```

This is more detailed from the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1485523310718777> in <module>
----> 1 drop_sdf_sales = azSynapse._delete_from_synapse(drop_sql, tempDir=temp_read_dir)

<command-1485523310718391> in _delete_from_synapse(self, sql, url, tempDir)
      5         if not tempDir:
      6             tempDir = self.azblob._get_blob_path('04-publish', 'sqlDwReadTempDirs')
----> 7         df = UtilAzSynapse.read_from_synapse(sql, url, tempDir)
      8         return df

<command-2362013028695578> in read_from_synapse(sql, url, tempDir)
     16                   .option("tempDir", tempDir)
     17                   .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true")
---> 18                   .option("query", sql)
     19                   .load()
     20              )

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    182             return self._df(self._jreader.load(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    183         else:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop Table in SQL Database from Azure Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62190993/drop-table-in-sql-database-from-azure-databricks)

Comment: @Kafels I think from your suggestion it has a similarity with my `read_from_synapse` script ? Because when I try to `DROP TABLE X` with my function, it got an JDBC error, but I will try it first, and I will update it to you

Comment: If your problem is dropping the table, yes.. it has a similarity. I would recommend you to update the question adding the stack trace from exception

Comment: @Kafels But I want to ask, is it possible to drop the external table from databricks such as Azure Synapse ? because when I see this [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics.html), it didn't explain that it can to drop some table or drop some row from it ?

Comment: I think you should take another approach to `delete` or `drop` like using a proper library provided from Azure Synapse. In my opinion, `spark.read.jdbc` should only run SELECT queries

Comment: @Kafels What library that can be used for Databricks that can drop the table ? I've tried your suggestion, and it got an error as I updated on my question.

Answer (score 1):

> To delete a row from the Azure Synapse table using Azure Databricks:

```
postActionsSQL = "DELETE from Persons WHERE PersonID=3"

df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://synapse.sql.azuresynapse.net:1433;database=master;user=master@synapse;password=XXXXXXX;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.sql.azuresynapse.net;loginTimeout=30;") \
  .option("tempDir", "wasbs://sampledata@synapse.blob.core.windows.net/temp") \
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
  .option("dbTable", "Persons") \
  .option("postActions",postActionsSQL) \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .save()
```

[image]

> To delete table from Azure Synapse table using Azure Databricks:

```
postActionsSQL = "DROP TABLE Trip003"

df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://synapse.sql.azuresynapse.net:1433;database=master;user=master@synapse;password=XXXXXXX;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.sql.azuresynapse.net;loginTimeout=30;") \
  .option("tempDir", "wasbs://sampledata@synapse.blob.core.windows.net/temp") \
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
  .option("dbTable", "Trip003") \
  .option("postActions",postActionsSQL) \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .save()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the your answer, but when I tried your script, it got an error 
`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'write'` , why it got a requirement like `write_to_synapse` function ?

Comment: Make sure the declare the dataframe before you write. Initially I had used `df = spark.read \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://synapse.sql.azuresynapse.net:1433;database=chepra;user=chepra@synapse;password=XXXXX;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=cheprasynapse.sql.azuresynapse.net;loginTimeout=30;") \
  .option("tempDir", "wasbs://sampledata@chepra.blob.core.windows.net/temp") \
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
  .option("dbTable", "trip") \
  .load()`

Comment: On "regular" Azure SQL with `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` this does not work. Error is: "does not allow create table as select". Error message is garbage, I have a `DROP TABLE` -clause.